# Error when getting token with status code: BadAuthentication while using Firebase cloud messaging to send push notification

Tags: java, android

I'm using Firebase Cloud Messaging to send push notification.Here is the code which i had used to send notification to the same device.

```
public SendNotificationTask(Context context) {
    this.context = context;
}

public SendNotificationTask(Context context, String title, String message) {
    this.context = context;
    this.title = title;
    this.message = message;
    SharedPreferences pref = context.getSharedPreferences(SHARED_PREF, 0);
    deviceToken = pref.getString("regId",null);
}

@Override
protected String doInBackground(String... strings) {
    System.out.println("in send notification AsyncTask");
   // String inputJson = strings[1];
    String result = "";
    String pushMessage = "{\"data\":{\"title\":\"" +
            title +
            "\",\"message\":\"" +
            message +
            "\"},\"to\":\"" +
            deviceToken +
            "\"}";


    try {
        //https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send
        URL url1 = new URL(strings[0]);
        HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) url1.openConnection();
        con.setRequestMethod("POST");
        String userCredentials = authUsername + ":" + authPassword;
        System.out.println("Basic Auth : " + userCredentials);
        byte[] authBytes = Base64.encodeBase64(userCredentials.getBytes());
        con.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "key=" + SERVER_KEY);
        con.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");
        con.setRequestProperty("Content-Language", "en-US");

        con.setDoInput(true);
        con.setDoOutput(true);
        //this creates body part of that connection then goto server & server reads it using input stream
        OutputStream out = con.getOutputStream();
        DataOutputStream dataOut = new DataOutputStream(out);
        //dataOut.writeBytes(inputJson);
        dataOut.writeBytes(pushMessage);
        //System.out.println("Input json is given");
        dataOut.flush();
        dataOut.close();

        //get server response----reading data from server
        if (con.getResponseCode() == 200) {
            InputStream is = con.getInputStream();
            Utilities.systemOutPrint("Input stream : "+is);
            int data;
            while (true) {
                data = is.read();
                if (data == -1) break;
                else
                    result = result + (char) data;
            }

        }//eof if
        else if (con.getResponseCode() == 409) {
            // Toast.makeText(context, "", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            result = "request could not be completed";

        }
        con.disconnect();
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }

    return result;
}


}
```

And I got the response too for the sending message. here is the response code

```
{"multicast_id":5927288239556944143,"success":1,"failure":0,"canonical_ids":0,"results":[{"message_id":"0:1498821718973437%9fbc6d3bf9fd7ecd"}]}
```

but I didn't get the expected result i.e push notification on my device. here is the error image : [error after getting response from the user](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yv0mc.png)
Please help me in this
For all your answers thanks in advance